# Batch/CMD: Adding files to Startup list

Tags: list, batch-file, startup

How can a batch file lists itself in the startup list of Windows???

It doesn't matter if it goes from the registry or not.

IF with the registry, please give also the command to DELETE the registry entry.

This should work under all versions from ME to 7 please.

Otherwise just XP/Vista/7.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create a task in task scheduler adding the files on Actions that trigger at Startup

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure i understand you, but if what you want is an easy way to execute a command/batch on startup, why not just put it in the `All Users\Startup` folder?
To do so programatically would just mean copying a file to that directory.
For example, in Windows Vista, the full path of that directory is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

(you can use replace the beginning of the line with `%ProgramData%` or `%AllUsers%\ProgramData` to make it more global - such as when Windows is installed on D:).

Comment: My Win8.1 install uses `Start-up` rather than `Startup`. Anyone know how to reach this folder more generically? Eg, shell:Common Startup - although this doesn't seem to work in a batch file.

Answer (score 4):

I do not use windows7 (might get a check at the beta shortly), but I think the correct place will always be better taken from the registry, because of the Windows versions being localized.  My own version of **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup** here looks more like **"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Menu Démarrer\Programmes\Démarrage"**  (from XP, of course)
-10 for programmers using hard-coded directory names (yes, some installers will create english/different language directories at installation).
-1 for Microsoft localising directory names...
Anyhow here is a snipet for this, valid for XP at least:

**commonstartup.cmd**

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=3 delims=    " %%k in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "Common Startup"^| findstr /i /c:"Common Startup"') do set StartUp=%%k
echo StartUp="%StartUp%"
```

**___Notes_____**
**1:** Because **reg.exe** from Windows2000 and XP have different command arguments, maybe the W7 one has changed too so test it before *set and forget*.
**2:** To get a list of all the system directories, issue the command: **reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"** and read the lines.  You might want to change the **"Common Startup"** for something else, if things are so different with W7.
**3:** There is also a personal/user list within **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** if you want this to be usable by some users only.

Comment: Doesn't work on Win7 - the output of reg is different so this returns REG_SZ. You could create a different version for Win7, although I'm going for the registry as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13880705/1308967)

Answer (score 0):

xcopy C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\Batch.bat C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\"Start Menu"\Programs\StartUp /O /X /E /H /K 
is the correct command for windows 10. simply change the the second path to your version, and remember whenever there is a space, place a " before the word before the space, and after the word after it.
however, it MUST be opened in administrator, so after some research, i found that a batch file could be used to start a different batch file and run it in administrative mode:
runas /user:administrator C:\data\mybatchfile.bat
that should work!