# shell:Common Startup as a parameter to XCOPY

Tags: shell, windows-7, batch-file, windows-xp

I have a simple batch script that copies a file to the startup folder, but it appears that I can't use shell:Common Startup as a parameter to xcopy. I have tried this

```
xcopy hurrdurr.exe "shell:Common Startup"
```

and many other variations, and they don't work. As an aside, if this did work, "hurrdurr.exe" would run on every startup right, assuming I got clearance via uac to do the xcopy operation? Would using a environment variable be better? The os in question is Windows XP and proceeding.

Comment: I would not recommend actually copying the file executable itself to the startup folder. If you want to use the startup folder it would be best to create a shortcut to the executable file and place that shortcut in the startup folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your shell command won't work, but if you need to get your program to load on startup then I would much prefer using the registry, it's cleaner and simpler, and it means you don't have to copy the file somewhere else, especially if that file is dependant on other things.

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v "Hurrdurr" /d "hurrdurr.exe" /f
```

Just run cmd as admin and it will work :)

If you do want to use the startup folder though, on Win7 you can use

```
"%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

I would also use a shortcut as @David suggested instead of copying the actual file.