# Application start on logon with Java

Tags: java, windows, startup

So my question today is one of personal academic willingness to learn, despite it probably being a little beyond my level. Bear with me on this!

I've made a simple application, that might look (and might BE) a little clunky. All it does is open a window, and have you press a button, to close said window.

Here's the code for this questionable construct:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StartupLearning extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JButton button;

public StartupLearning() {

    super("If you see this box on startup, you've learned something new today!");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    button = new JButton("Close this box");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setActionCommand("Close");
    add(button);
    pack();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

    if (cmd.equals("Close"))
        dispose();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new StartupLearning().setSize(400, 75);
        }

    });
}
}
```

I know it's not perfect, and I know it probably has faults that could be optimized and organized, but like mentioned, this is just me trying to teach myself something new.

Now, what I wonder about is what code I can use, and how I can use said code to make this one very simple application run when a user logs in to Windows (let's leave cross-platform out of it, if it makes things even more complicated)?

For someone about as green as he sounds, what class or code would best suit this job, and how can I use it with my presented code?

All that needs to happen, is that this simple code needs to run when the user is logged in, and close when the user hits the button.

**EDIT**

Thanks to you three who answered, and I have clearly not been specific enough. I need my little pretty code to run on login without any user input or moving of the file.

The application needs to be able to run on start up right after the user has launched it once.

Meaning that I'd run the app, and from now on, it will always run on start up, until I delete the application or tell it in the source that it will no longer do so.

**EDIT2**

You guys are awesome for bearing with me this long. To further clarify:

Assume the user is the administrator, and there is no password or any form of protection is being used. No anti-virus or anti-spyware or firewall or anything. No defenses at all.

Assume the `.jar` file and `.class` file are both in `C:\`.

Assume the application will be run once manually, before a start-at-login is expected to happen. This is when the application gets its chance to add itself to the registry or put a `.bat` in the startup folder or something.

Don't worry so much about the ethics, as I'm just trying to establish how a simple Java app can start itself in the every time I reboot.

Could I perhaps have the application put a shortcut of itself in the startup folder or something?

Or could I have it add itself to the registry after the user runs the app?

I know I'm asking a lot, but could I have a demonstration of something like this?

You guys are my heroes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Run At Login (manually)

Once you packaged your app, you can just put `java -jar your-app.jar` in a `.bat` file in the Windows *startup* menu.

If you don't want to create a `jar` (e.g. because your app is simple enough) and always assuming you have your Java environment variables configured (`JAVA_HOME`, `PATH`....), you can just run directly your bytecode:

`startup.bat`:

```
cd your/app/bytecode/path
java yourapp
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154701/batch-cmd-adding-files-to-startup-list) how to start an app at startup.

### Run at Startup (manually)

If you need the application to run *before* the user login you can use the **Windows Task Scheduler**, and use the trigger *at startup*, wrapping your application as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12034739/2200058) OS answer:

> ```
> @echo off
> REM Eventually change directory to the program directory 
> cd C:\Users\User1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Facebook\dist\
> REM run the program
> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\User1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Facebook\dist\Facebook.jar"
> ```

### Run at Startup (installer)

In case you really don't want any user interaction the only easy (and IMHO ethic) solution I imagine is the *Installer*.

You basically need a wizard installing your application for you (and for the user) configuring it to run at startup. There are many wizards, you can build your own or start your research having a look [here](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/java.html).

### Run at Startup (standalone)

Use the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852599/2200058), writing something like this directly in your small application (original post [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/378321/java/java/Add-application-start)):

```
static final String REG_ADD_CMD = "cmd /c reg add \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\" /v \"{0}\" /d \"{1}\" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ";
private void exec(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    if (args.length != 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\n\nUsage: java SetEnv {key} {value}\n\n");

    String key = args[0];
    String value = args[1];

    String cmdLine = MessageFormat.format(REG_ADD_CMD, new Object[] { key, value });

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine);
}
```

`Key` is your app name (not relevant), `Value` is your jar file or the .bat command that runs your application (see above methods on how to package a jar or run a .class inside a .bat file), e.g.  `"C:\Users\YourApp.jar"`

**NOTE**

As stated by the author, this approach **should** work with any versions of Windows, since they all use the same `Startup\Run` registry entry. Though, keep in mind that this is not portable and you have probably to tune the script according to the MS OS version.

**NOTE 2**

Think twice before modifying the registry code directly from your application (the *hacky* way). For doing that you probably need Supervisor/Admin priviledges **every** time the application runs. Moreover doing that without correct, explicit user prompt can be seen as a malware/spam malicious practice.

Comment: Forgive my lack of information. Could you please update your answer to reflect my added information in the edit?

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that! Still, I'm a little confused as to how the code snippet you provided could be integrated into my little app? Assuming my `.java.` file is in `C:\StartupLearning.java`, how could I use what you showed me? I know I must be sounding a little thick, by the way, so thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: You first need to **compile** your java file to have the .class bytecode ([javac.exe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) command). Then you will need to find your java.exe to **run** your .class file. Your code should look like:
`cd C:\direcory-containing-the-class-file`

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe StartupLearning`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in the OP's edit. The aim is to have the application run once manually, and from that point on the application starts itself when Windows starts. Essentially, using Java code, the application should make the necessary changes to auto-start itself.

Comment: I appreciate the update, and I appreciate you and @RobF taking the time to argue what the best approach for my question is. And you're right Alex, I'm starting to smell the ethical dilemmas by having the app start itself after first launch. But I still feel that, though these answers are great, none of them allow my little source-code to launch at login without "help". I'll update my OP one last time to reflect this.

Comment: Edited again, I hope this one will fulfil your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options to run your application when Window starts:

1. Place a shortcut to the application in the startup directory, [see here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7).
2. Setup a java service wrapper to start your Java application on Windows startup.
3. Use the Task Scheduler in Windows to execute the `java -jar yourfile.jar` command when Windows starts.

Out of all of these options, the startup directory would be the easiest option and sounds like it'll do what you want.

**EDIT**

Doing what you described in your edit, you will probably need to edit the registry to add your application to the list of applications that launch on startup.

Take a look [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/378321/java/java/Add-application-start) for some details on how you can do that.

In essence, you want to add an entry to the registry at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\<YourKeyAsAString>` with the value as the path to your application.

Comment: That "wrapper" thing sounds interesting. Could it do what I wanted, taking into account my OP edit?

Comment: Updated the answer, you probably want to look into adding the application to the registry for startup applications.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. But the CodeRanch forum has a few dead links, so I might not be getting the full picture here. Could you perhaps demonstrate how I could have my application add that entry to the registry when first run? Assuming my `.java.` file is in `C:\StartupLearning.java`? I'm just having a little trouble picturing it all in my code.

Answer (score 0):

As RobF said, you can create a shortcut in the Startup directory. You can also create a registry entry, see [here](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/109/).